# Error When Exporting Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, desktop-application

An unhandled exception of type `System.AccessViolationException` occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: What CR version you are using?

Comment: Service Pack 1 (13.0.1)